# Crystal report shows database login when taking Dataset as datasource

Tags: c#, authentication, crystal-reports, credentials

In my project i use EF4, but the connection string of the EF Context are dynamically generated and not saved in any Configuration file, everything works fine...

When i want to use Crystal report to view my reports, I used Datasets that import data form the my Entities (linq), and than set the Datasets as Datasources to the reports [Here Is A Tutorial](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-crystal-report-entity-framework.htm)

But at the moment of the display (in the CrystalReportViewer) a login prompt window pops up, asking for Login & Password (also the Server name and database name but the fields are disabled)

[image]

I Googled and i noticed that most of the solutions proposed concentrate around : Setting credentials in the code (like this) :

```
ConnectionInfo crconnectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
crconnectioninfo.ServerName = "localhost";
crconnectioninfo.DatabaseName = "dbclients";
crconnectioninfo.UserID = "ssssssss";
crconnectioninfo.Password = "xxxxxxx";
```

but here is how i create my report :

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = container.NewRow();
    dr = CreateRowFromMirrorRow(dr, i); //Methode that creates a Row
    container.Rows.Add(dr);
}

objRpt.SetDataSource(container.DefaultView);

// Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
crystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

My questions are :

- Why do i have to pass any database credentials since there is no direct connection between the CrReport or the Dataset with the Database?
- How do i set the credential of a Dataset (or crystal report) using a ConnectionInfo  object (in my case)?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when you have Crystal Reports asking for credentials when it's not supposed to, there's something wrong that appears unrelated on the surface.

I think you might be able to get it to work if you don't call `Refresh` on the viewer, but call refresh on the report itself instead:

```
objRpt.SetDataSource(container.DefaultView);
objRpt.Refresh();

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
// Don't refresh viewer!
// If you have any report parameters, set them through the viewer here.
```

---

If for some reason, if you do need to set the connection for Crystal Report in the future, you can use this on the report before setting the report viewer's `ReportSource`:

```
foreach (Table crTable in report.Database.Tables)
{
    TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
    var connectionInfo = tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

    // use connectionInfo to set database credentials

    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
}
```